# Powerful mini ATX gaming PC and extreme low power hungry download server in ONE

Tags: router, power-supply, computer-building, gaming, low-power

I want to build a really **powerful gaming machine** with some kind of a media server streaming full HD contents to the whole room and TV, but at the same time, a "magical button" which turns this power hungry machine into a really **low power consuming web, download,.. server.**

I mean, is it generally possible with the present Hardware to switch to an extreme economical modes ? I am talking about CPU, graphic card etc.. The switch could be from 400 W to 30 W or somehing about these values. Of course, in the second low power mode, I do now want any performance. Try to turn off everything what is not needed for a basic network functionality and HDD. I would say, that the button should transform this pc into a very quiet, slow pc. Or, if possible, after a period of time, automatically switch into this mode.

I am asking because I was using an asus rt n16 router with DD WRT on it router for this low power purpose, but... 1 PC is 1 PC. And it wasn't really stable by streaming etc.

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a magical switch that will take an idle system that takes X watts and make it use Y watts.

Comment: But I do not understand why. Why couldn't all those components switch all cores off, and auto-underclock cpu's etc?

Comment: Because there is no market to make a switch that prevents the potential performance of a system from being allowed.  If you want a **really powerful gaming machine** it comes at a cost of requring additional power and knowing your idle power will be more then a normal machine with a 400W power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idle CPU and GPU will consume less power than one fully loaded.  This has been true for a while.  Modern Intel and possibly AMD CPUs have technologies that allow changing of the clock rate by the operating system (read the [Intel SpeedStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) Wikipedia article), and this is supported by all modern operating systems.

Hard disks can be powered down when not in use.  In the Windows power control panel, there's a plethora of power-saving options that you can experiment with.

The "extreme economical mode" on the PC platform is sleep, hybrid sleep, and hibernation modes.  There's a lot you can do to manage power usage on a PC (and desktops/laptops now consume less power than before, so you're getting more bang for your power nowadays than ever before).  But, there's no hardware you can add on to a PC to make it go into a super low-power mode.

You ought to offload your download tasks to an ARM based system such as your router or something like a Raspberry Pi, and shut down or hibernate/sleep your gaming system when not in use.

Comment: OK Let's say that the DL task would do the Raspberry. The question is, what devices is able to send more full hd streams over network ? (air + cable). The Routers itself are not that powerfull..

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me - Your router should have no problem keeping up with the http requests of the number of clients you use.